# Unable to create token file for file storage on dropbox through sharpbox. IO Exception occurring

Tags: file, exception, token, dropbox, sharpbox

```
I want to store file on dropbox through sharpbox.I followed their own basic tutorial in which they said to create the token file from dropbox token authorization tool provided in the project itself after installing nuget package but I am unable to generate it.Error 404 occurs.Below is my code which I wrote for creating token file in order to store files on dropbox.In this code following exception 

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'E:\test.txt' because it is being used by another process"

occurs at Line
var fs = File.Open(@"E:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None).
```

In the code provided below I am trying to write the access token values obtained on the file created but exception is coming described above.Please correct this code for getting the correct token file as I need this file to proceed further.

Here is my code:

```
using AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox;
using AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.StorageProvider.DropBox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreatingtokenFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //CloudStorage dropBoxStorage = new CloudStorage();
            CloudStorage storageNew = new CloudStorage();
            // enter the comsumer key and secret
            String ConsumerKey = "**********";
            String ComsumerSecret = "**************";

            // 0. load the config
            DropBoxConfiguration config = DropBoxConfiguration.GetStandardConfiguration();
            config.AuthorizationCallBack = new Uri("http://google.com");
            // 1. get the request token from dropbox
            DropBoxRequestToken requestToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxRequestToken(config, ConsumerKey, ComsumerSecret);
            //requestToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxRequestToken(config, ConsumerKey, ComsumerSecret);

            // 2. build the authorization url based on request token                        
            String url = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxAuthorizationUrl(config, requestToken);

            ////Save token to Session
            // HttpContext.Current.Session["requestToken"] = requestToken;

            // 3. Redirect the user to the website of dropbox
            // ---> DO IT <--
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
            // ---> if not, you will get an unauthorized exception <--
            // 



            //this line does create a file but it's empty, so what we need to do is to save the access token in this file
            Stream xmlStream = File.Create(@"E:\test.txt");

            //
            // 4. Exchange the request token into access token
            using (var fs = File.Open(@"E:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {
                ICloudStorageAccessToken accessToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.ExchangeDropBoxRequestTokenIntoAccessToken(config, ConsumerKey, ComsumerSecret, requestToken);
                //ICloudStorageAccessToken accessToken1;
                accessToken = storageNew.DeserializeSecurityToken(fs);
                storageNew.Open(config, accessToken);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file in this line:

```
Stream xmlStream = File.Create(@"E:\test.txt");
```

and then you try to open it again here:

```
File.Open(@"E:\test.txt", ...)
```

So, as the error says, you're trying to open a file that is already in use.

Comment: Any code that doesn't try to open the same file twice (or at least closes the file in between).